# Redirct all subfolder to new domain except wp-admin login page

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-location, wpmu

I've added a 301 redirect to a subfolder from example.com /id to  -example/net/id

```
location /id/ {
return 301 https://www.example.net/$request_uri ; 
}
```

can i exclude my wp-admin login page so i can still view it in my old domain?